# serenity cucumber browser unique session per feature

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm looking at serenity (the following versions)

```
<serenity.version>1.1.26</serenity.version>
 <serenity.maven.version>1.1.26</serenity.maven.version>
 <serenity.cucumber.version>1.1.5</serenity.cucumber.version>
```

I have feature files F1, F2, F3.

I'm looking for support to run all the scenarios in F1 (only) to run in a single browser session.

The scenarios in F2 and F3 can run in a "browser per scenario" mode.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you need more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber hooks do the job for you.

```
import cucumber.annotation.After;
import cucumber.annotation.Before;

public static WebDriver DRIVER;

@Before
public void setUp() {
  // start browser if it does not exist yet
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
  // clean cookies
}
```

Note that I use the cucumber before, not the JUnit before.Do make sure you have a reference to the `DRIVER` in your tests. The hooks wil run before and after each scenario (or example if you use scenario outline). If you want a specific setup for certain annotated features, for example:

```
@slowtest
Feature: F1 feature
```

Then you can use:

```
import cucumber.annotation.After;
import cucumber.annotation.Before;

public static WebDriver DRIVER;

@Before("@slowtest")
public void setUp() {
  // start browser if it does not exist yet
}

@After("@slowtest")
public void tearDown() {
  // close browser or clean cookies, or....
}
```

Conclusion you can use cucumber hooks in combination with annotations in features for custom setup and teardown.

Comment: Where does it specify that OP will have separate browser for each feature file?