# Testing different Scenarios in “Selenium Cucumber with Java” without opening new Web browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a feature file where i have 2 scenarios

```
Feature: Login to Online Store

Scenario: Login successful with valid credentials
    Given User is on Home Page
    When User navigates to Login Page
    And User provides username and password
    Then Message displays Login successfully

Scenario: User logout successfully
    When User logouts from application
    Then Message displays Logout successfully
```

Every time I run the **RunFeatures.java** file, after the first Scenario, driver to open new Browser to execute next Scenario. **Can we use the same browser to execute the 2nd scenario?**
Below is my code:

RunFeatures.java

```
package cucumbertest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features/"
            ,glue={"steps"}
            ,dryRun=false
            ,monochrome=false)

public class RunFeatures
{
}
```

ClientSteps.java:

```
package steps;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.en.*;
import pages.HomePage;
import pages.LoginPage;

public class ClientSteps
{
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    @Given("^User is on Home Page$")
    public void user_is_on_Home_Page() throws Throwable {
        new HomePage(driver).user_is_on_Home_Page();
    }

    @When("^User navigates to Login Page$")
    public void user_navigates_to_Login_Page() throws Throwable {
        new HomePage(driver).user_navigates_to_Login_Page();
    }

    @When("^User provides username and password$")
    public void user_provides_username_and_password() throws Throwable {
        new LoginPage(driver).user_provides_username_and_password();
    }

    @Then("^Message displays Login successfully$")
    public void message_displays_Login_successfully() throws Throwable {
        new LoginPage(driver).message_displays_Login_successfully();
    }

    @When("^User logouts from application$")
    public void user_logouts_from_application() throws Throwable {
        new LoginPage(driver).user_Logout_from_the_Application();
    }

    @Then("^Message displays Logout successfully$")
    public void message_displays_Logout_successfully() throws Throwable {
        new LoginPage(driver).message_displayed_Logout_successfully();
    }
}
```

Homepage.java file

```
package pages;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class HomePage
{
    WebDriver driver;


    public HomePage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;     

    }
    public void user_is_on_Home_Page() throws Throwable {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

    }

    public void user_navigates_to_Login_Page() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();
    }

}
```

LoginPage.java

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class LoginPage
{
    WebDriver driver;
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void user_provides_username_and_password() throws Throwable {
        // This is to get the first data of the set (First Row + First Column)
        driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("tri.nguyen");
        // This is to get the first data of the set (First Row + Second Column)
        driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("Test@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
    }


    public void message_displays_Login_successfully() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Login Successfully");
    }

    public void user_Logout_from_the_Application() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement (By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a")).click();
    }


    public void message_displayed_Logout_successfully() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Logout Successfully");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because you instantiate the WebDriver in your steps class. You should look into using hooks. I did some research and found that cucumber-jvm doesn't support global hooks by default but there are workarounds you could try.

Comment: Thank you @RemcoW. Can you please tell me more details about hooks? I am new with Selenium.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547776/serenity-cucumber-browser-unique-session-per-feature/35720040#35720040

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice, test cases should be atomic. Automation Test case shouldn't be dependent on another test case for browser instance, data etc.

You rather should close all browser windows after every test case and open browser again as a new instance for a next test case.

Use @Before and @After in your stefdef file to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have any document/source I can refer to?

Comment: This is good read. (http://www.sustainabletdd.com/). I have book written by author on this blog, I may publish something with examples to make it simple on my own blog (http://testautomationsimplified.com/).

Comment: I may agree only partial of this theory. We should try to mimic our test cases to as much possible as real users and as a user I will not close the browser after every single transaction. I would want to pass the driver instance to my test cases randomly.

Comment: You may not want to fail next test case if your browser window gets closed for some reason. This may happen for multiple reasons. Think about running your daily/nightly suite on a grid/server along with thousands other selenium tests, browser failure can be very common thing.

Comment: here is excerpt from [The Cucumber for Java Book ](https://pragprog.com/book/srjcuc/the-cucumber-for-java-book). Book is written by inventors of cucumber. When writing a scenario, here's is a really important concept you need to grasp: Each scenario must make sense and be able to executed independently of any other scenario. Chapter 3 pg 38

Answer (score 1):

as I am not able to add as a comment due to word restrictions, writing it here as a answer again! This is in continuation to my previous post. You can try this. Replace @Given by following

```
WebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp(){
        driver.quit();
    }
    @Given("^User is on Home Page$")
    public void user_is_on_Home_Page() throws Throwable {
        new HomePage(driver).user_is_on_Home_Page();
    }
```

make sure you import following files only and not junit*

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify my codes following your instruction but its getting NullPointer exception:

```
WebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp(){
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Given("^User is on Home Page$")
    public void user_is_on_Home_Page() throws Throwable {
        new HomePage(driver).user_is_on_Home_Page();
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pages.HomePage.user_is_on_Home_Page(HomePage.java:24)
    at steps.ClientSteps.user_is_on_Home_Page(ClientSteps.java:30)
    at ✽.Given User is on Home Page(Login.feature:4)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at steps.ClientSteps.cleanUp(ClientSteps.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm again not able to add it as a comment :(.
You have declared and instantiated driver variable inside setup method which makes it local to setup method only. Declare driver at class level.

```
WebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    }
```

This should work. Let me know in case you face any issues, we may get on hangout to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet, it still doesnt work. org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='account_logout']/a"}
Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds.
After the 1st scenario run ended, browser getting closed. I want the 2nd scenario to continue after 1st scenario without closing browser and instance a new one. Is it possible?

Comment: its a diff issue now. Looks like a synchronization issue to me. add Implicit wait. if your xpath is correct and its visible on the page then this would solve the issue. add this in your setup method after driver = new FirefoxDriver(). `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet, as I said before. The 2nd scenario will base on 1st scenario hence browser after 1st scenario cannot be closed so that the element can be located by driver in 2nd scenario. Is it possible? Anyway, my hangout is **quangtringuyen2005**

Comment: You can do it with normal junit test case by declaring driver variable inside @BeforeClass or declaring inside constructor. With cucumber I don't think that's even possible as for every scenario your stefdef class in invoked so its treated as a new instance.